# REGEX validador de email

Tags: regex

El objetivo de mi `regex` es que valide una dirección de **mail** que podría o no existir según los siguientes parámetros:

- no contiene caractéres distintos de letras, números, guiones bajos y @
- sólo 1 @
- antes del @, deben haber entre 3 y 8 caracteres
- después del arroba, deben haber en total entre 4 y 12 caracteres, con exactamente un punto.

La expresión que tengo hasta ahora me permite controlar que hayan entre 4 y 12 caracteres antes del punto después del arroba, pero no logro modificarla para que cumpla con los requisitos pedidos.

La expresión es:

> ^(?=[^@]{3,8}@)([\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@(?=.{4,12}.[^.]*$)[\w-]*[a-zA-Z0-9].[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo suelo utilizar esta web, [generador de expresiones regulares](http://txt2re.com/) ,para generar algunas expresiones regulares y te permite elegir lenguaje de programación para la expresión.

1. Solo tienes que ingresar el formato requerido
2. Luego de das en "Show Matches"
3. Y te mostrar las sugerencias para que puedas ir armando la expresión.

para un ejemplo

el correo : prueba123@hotmail.com

expresión regular para javascript:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script language=javascript>
      var txt='prueba123@hotmail.com';

      var re1='([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})';    // Email Address 1

      var p = new RegExp(re1,["i"]);
      var m = p.exec(txt);
      if (m != null)
      {
          var email1=m[1];
          document.write("("+email1.replace(/</,"&lt;")+")"+"\n");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva.